# How to generate a [0,1,0,1,0,1,0....,0,1] vector with length 2n

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I was wondering as to how to generate this kind of vector. I'm having trouble with where and how to specify the length and how to put 0s and 1s in that order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here at the same time an array is allocated and filled:

```
 result(2:2:2*n)=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution using [`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html):

```
result = repmat([0, 1], 1, n);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
result = mod(0:2*n-1, 2);
```

Also:

```
result = kron(ones(1,n), [0 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This method uses [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to make a 2-by-n matrix with 0s on the first row and 1s on the second, then [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)s to form the desired matrix:

```
result = reshape(meshgrid(0:1, 1:n)', 1, 2*n);
```

Answer (score 0):

A funny question, an other way

`result = reshape([zeros(1,n); ones(1,n)], 1,2*n)`